# JMeter retrieve value of value

Tags: jmeter, nested, ldap, performance-testing

I am using jmeter to test ldap.
As part of my test, I want to search for a random uid on each iteration. I did not find a straight forward answer to this. So my idea was to first select a random number 1-200 and saving that number as a variable named uid, that number would correspond to a UDV name.

For example

```
uid = 2 and 2 = A123456
```

in my udv list. However when trying to reference this variable in my ldap search filter.I am trying to use

```
(uid=${${uid}})
```

in hopes to get the value of the value of uid. However the search results just show this as a string.

```
<searchfilter>(uid=${${uid}})</searchfilter>
```

Is there another way to achieve what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [__V](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) function

```
 ${__V(${uid})}
```

> The V (variable) function returns the result of evaluating a variable name expression. This can be used to evaluate nested variable references
>
> ${__V(A${N})} - works OK. A${N} becomes A1, and the __V function returns the value of A1

Comment: Works beautifully! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest would be going for [__RandomFromMultipleVars() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomFromMultipleVars)?

Another option is using [__V() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V), it can [combine and evaluate JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables/)